# Keep firstly found duplicate items in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[(1, 0.3), (3, 0.2), (3, 0.15), (1, 0.07), (1, 0.02), (2, 0.01)]
```

I want to keep the firstly found duplicate items in this list, based on the first item in every tuple:

```
[(1, 0.3), (3, 0.2), (2, 0.01)]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a generator function you can lazily return the first dupes, all you need to store are the keys which will be gc'd once the function ends:

```
def first_found(l):
    seen = set()
    for k, v in l:
        if k not in seen:
            yield (k, v)
        seen.add(k)
```

Which for your list would give you:

```
print(list(first_found(l)))
[(1, 0.3), (3, 0.2), (2, 0.01)]
```

Or to update the original list:

```
l[:] = first_found(l)
```

Or to create a dict:

```
od = OrderedDict(first_found(l))

print(od)
OrderedDict([(1, 0.3), (3, 0.2), (2, 0.01)])
```

Comment: Really nice solution!

Answer (score 7):

If order of the resulting list does not matter, only that it contains the first entry from the original list for each tuple: reverse the list first, then pass it through `dict` to remove duplicates and keep the *last* entry for each key (the *first* in the original list, since it’s been reversed):

```
>>> items = [(1, 0.3), (3, 0.2), (3, 0.15), (1, 0.07), (1, 0.02), (2, 0.01)]
>>> list(dict(reversed(items)).items())
[(1, 0.3), (2, 0.01), (3, 0.2)]
```

If order of the resulting list matters, see Padraic’s answer :)

Comment: This will not maintain the original order of elements. Apart from that it will work fine.

Comment: Good point Padraic. I updated the answer to use `reversed()`. On Python 3 there will be no more copies with this solution than with using a for loop. On Python 2 if `items()` is replaced with `iteritems()` then there will be no more copies than with using a for loop.

Comment: Good point – given that that would copy the list anyway, I’ve reverted the `LastUpdatedOrderedDict` example to just use `[::-1]` to reverse the list.

Comment: `OrderedDict` supports `reversed()` directly on the object, to iterate backwards over the keys, so I used that to avoid the `[::-1]` reversal which was an additional copy.